# Verticly center divs in one column design

Tags: css, html, scroll

I am back to html/css after a long hiatus and need some help.

Background: I am using a 1 column layout and jQuery to auto scroll the page to the various divs when the user interacts with a fixed nav bar.

Problem: when you view the page on either a screen with a larger vertical resolution than my laptop or a mobile device you can see all or some of the different div sections at once.

Question: is there a way to vertically separate the divs so that the scrolling functions similar to if  I used a traditional nav bar that linked to different files? In other words, I don't want to see all the divs at once, just the one the user clicked on.

thanks a lot!

Comment: Show us [what you have tried](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com).

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="content">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="pseudopage">
            foo
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

With that basic structure (repeating the "container" divs), you can then do this:

```
​#content{
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: DESIRED_HEIGHT;
    width: DESIRED_WIDTH;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.container {          
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
}

.pseudopage {
    vertical-align:middle;  
    display:inline-block;
    margin:px;
}
div.container:before{
    content: '';        
    height:100%;
    width: 0px;
    margin:0px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Enjoy!  Also, the #content div, could very well be the body of the page, but you have to remember to set a height.  (Pro tip - if you set the height of the `html` to 100% and the `body` to 100%, then you will fill the screen.)

Comment: So the container is really what you're aligning and the pseudopage is displayed in the middle is that correct? It worked I just want to understand why.

Comment: Yes, you align the container to be the size of the page.  by making the container invisible, it will automatically grow when the screen size changes, pushing the other information out the edges of the content div.  You can then align the pseudopage div however you like in the container div, and you can always be sure that it will be relative to the full page.